# What is wrong with the following code for Parse.com Parse.Cloud define and Run and callbacks

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Re-asked question with real code VS sudo code at
[Having problems with some code on Parse.com's Cloud Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787213/having-problems-with-some-code-on-parse-coms-cloud-code)

/*
What am I doing wrong here?

I didn't want to re-write all my code to work with Parse.Cloud.run so I decided to make a function that would do that for me.

Error Message:

Update failed with Could not load triggers.  The error was TypeError: Object # has no method 'request'

*/

```
Parse.Cloud.define("httpx", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: request.params.url,
        method: request.params.method,
        headers: request.params.headers
    }, {
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            response.success(httpResponse);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            response.error(httpResponse);
        }
    });
});

function sendRequest(path, method, callback) {
    if (!initialized) {
        throw 'not initialized, call initialize(username, password) first before calling the API';
    }
    // Allows for only 2 paramiters to be passed if no method passed.
    if (typeof method == 'function') {
        callback = method;
        method = 'GET';
    }
    var type = (useHttps) ? 'http://' : 'https://';
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    var request = Parse.Cloud.run("httpx", {
        url: type + 'rest.website.com/' + path,
        method: method,
        headers: headers
    }, {
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            if (callback) {
                callback(httpResponse.text);
            }
            response.success(httpResponse.text);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            callback(httpResponse.status);
            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        }
    });
    //////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response.success(httpResponse.text);
```

where do you define response object?

Comment: Well, Parse.com has it defined in there HttpRequest but I don't quite understand callbacks yet to know what I was to do.